# Why is the notion of a batch problematic for RNNs?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, batch-normalization

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11604v2.pdf) says that the notion of a batch problematic for RNNs (page 9) (which is why you can't apply batch normalization for RNNs?). Why is it hard to talk about batches for RNNs?

Eg. the [Pytorch API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html) even has a parameter to control the batch size, so batches "clearly" make sense for RNNs (and, therefore, batch normalization also make sense).

What's going on?

Comment: My guess: for example, a batch of data for NLP RNN could consist of pieces of text of varying length, so they are of not the same size word-wise.

Comment: I think they imply the characteristic of RNNs, modelling temporal correlations and dependency structure. We can't just randomly sample batches arbitrarily in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The passage you refer to on page 9 says

> Layer
> Normalization [1] performs normalization over the entire layer instead of the batch, which is suitable
> for contexts where the notion of a batch is problematic (e.g. recurrent neural networks).

This is a single-sentence summary of a whole article; the symbol [1] is a citation to Jimmy Lei Ba, Jamie Ryan Kiros, and Geoffrey E Hinton. "[Layer normalization](https://www.cs.utoronto.ca/%7Ehinton/absps/LayerNormalization.pdf)." arXiv preprint
arXiv:1607.06450, 2016.

The key part of the cited article says

> The recent sequence to sequence models [Sutskever et al., 2014] utilize compact recurrent neural
> networks to solve sequential prediction problems in natural language processing. It is common
> among the NLP tasks to have different sentence lengths for different training cases. This is easy to
> deal with in an RNN because the same weights are used at every time-step. But when we apply batch
> normalization to an RNN in the obvious way, we need to to compute and store separate statistics for
> each time step in a sequence. This is problematic if a test sequence is longer than any of the training
> sequences. Layer normalization does not have such problem because its normalization terms depend
> only on the summed inputs to a layer at the current time-step. It also has only one set of gain and
> bias parameters shared over all time-steps.

And more details and development are provided in the complete text.